# Linux ld: What's the meaning of `-m` option and the command `ld -melf_32 -Ttext 0 -e startup_32`

Tags: linux, linker, ld

I have read the ld manual, the `-m emulation` option refers to `emulate the emulation linker`, what's the meaning of the description. And the `-T scriptfile` option can `use scriptfile as the linker script`, but what the option `-Ttext 0` refers to, is it valid?

Comment: @LukePark This is a compiling question, seems relevant to me.

Comment: Apologies, thought the command said `ls` and not `ld`, I read too fast!

Comment: You are kind-hearted, but I want to know which problems is not the programming questions, and where I can post the no-programming questions?@LukePark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-Ttext 0` tells the linker to start the program at address `0`

> 15.3 Linker emulation selection
>
> A linker emulation is a "personality" of the linker, which gives the linker default values for the other aspects of the target system. In particular, it consists of
>
> the linker script
>
> the target
>
> several "hook" functions that are run at certain stages of the linking process to do special things that some targets require

http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/binutils/html_node/binutils_20.html

Comment: But can the `-T` option use some other linker script commands, like `-Tdata 0x1000`?@xvan

Comment: Not sure if code execution can start on data segments, because first you'd need to fill those segments.